# Replacing Pandas index with row values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

***Task***:

I would like to replace index values (i.e `0,1,2,3,4` etc.) with the values under `Main`, while removing `Main` as it no longer has use.

`df`:

```
                  Main             Ing 
0                  A              Apple            
1                  B              Bread            
2                  Z              Cheese            
3                  E              Egg            
4                  D              Dough           
5                  X              Pasta
```

***My Goal***:

Output:

```
                Ing 
A              Apple            
B              Bread            
Z              Cheese            
E              Egg            
D              Dough           
X              Pasta
```

I'm sure it's a pretty simple solution but I have no idea. ***Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Main')
print (df)
         Ing
Main        
A      Apple
B      Bread
Z     Cheese
E        Egg
D      Dough
X      Pasta
```

If need remove index name `Main` add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Main').rename_axis(None)
print (df)
      Ing
A   Apple
B   Bread
Z  Cheese
E     Egg
D   Dough
X   Pasta
```

Or set it to `None`:

```
df = df.set_index('Main')
df.index.name = None
print (df)
      Ing
A   Apple
B   Bread
Z  Cheese
E     Egg
D   Dough
X   Pasta
```